# VS Studio now including global.json in every project and .netCore?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core-1.0

I installed R tools for Visual Studio because I am doing some class work where I need to use R, but after installing that every time I start a new project it loads .netCore Nuget package and I have a solution folder with global.json file in it and a src folder with the rest of the project...

What is going on with this?  If I get rid of the Nuget package nothing works, saying it can't find the target framework, etc...Unsure why or how this got installed but I don't like it...from what I am seeing it has something to do with a version of ASP.Net...how do I restore functionality back to normal and not have to load .netCore for every project??

Comment: i think by default your project must be targeting .net framework 5.0 which is .net core. when you create a new project, target 4.6 or below to get the old functionality back? try reading on dnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest version of Visual Studio **as of right now when I'm posting this** (Sept 12th 2016) includes `.NET Core 1.0` and the `RC2 Tooling`.

So when you create a new project, you'll need to read what type of project you wish to create.

Check out this dialog window, when I create a new project:

[image]

Ok - RED boxes are the new .NET Core project type, which includes that `*.json` file, while the BLUE boxes are your old school/more traditional way, with the `.csproj`, etc.

So read the options and choose what you would like, first.

BONUS SIDE TIP: `global.json` will be [leaving in the next update](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/05/23/changes-to-project-json/).